# How to setting data tables (pagination, style exc)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I am new in jQuery, I want to remove the pagination, and make my own style of the search, order, and pagination too

[heres my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67j1X.png)

my problem :
1. how could I remove the pagination
2. how could I styling the search input, and the pagination because isn't look good

i've tried removing the pagination bu it couldn't work
here's my code

```
   $(function () {
         $("#data").DataTable({
            paging: false,
            scrollY: 400
         });

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your DataTable constructor object:

```
"bPaginate": false
```